# Find a PDF on a finite set of powers of $2$, whose mean is a given power of $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Given $k$, find $n \in N$ and $p_i$ such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i 2^i = 2^k$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i = 1$$
$$0<p_i<1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $n=k+1$, $p_i=\dfrac{2^k}{2^{k+1}k+1}$ for every $0\leqslant i\leqslant k$ and $p_{k+1}=\dfrac{2^k(k-1)+1}{2^{k+1}k+1}$ (knowing that there are plenty of other solutions).

Comment: Maybe you mean $p_i=\dfrac{2^k}{2^{k+1}k-2^k+1}$ for every $0\leqslant i\leqslant k$ and $p_{k+1}=\dfrac{2^k(k-1)+1}{2^{k+1}k-2^k+1}$. Otherwise it doesn't sum to 1. 
By the way it doesn't work, for example for k=3.

Comment: I mean what is written, the $p_i$ do sum to $1$ and the example does work for every $k$. By the way I admire the way you approach the solutions suggested to you.

Comment: My mistake. Your solution is right. Thank you!